# PHP cache control - force image reload

Tags: php, image, caching, browser

I have a tool generating invoices with QR code (server running PHP 8.0.25). I am having a problem with the QR code after invoice is edited, the amount is not changed. Every time invoice is displayed script checks whether there is a file (png) with QR code already generated for given invoice, if yes then the png file is deleted and new one is generated. Unfortunately when I scan the QR code the change is not reflected, the amount is the old value.
The file with QR code is changed - when I download it after invoice is displayed, ie a new QR code generated. So I assume it's the problem with image caching.

This is in my headers (PHP):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT");
```

and also (HTML):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

This does not work for some reason. I searched here and elsewhere and the thing that is often advised is to use a parameter in img src. I tried that too but does not help: `<img src="'.$qr_file.'?q='.Date('U').'" />`
which looks like this in the HTML source, for example: `<img src="qr/1-20220004.png?q=1668573122">`

Tried in the latest version of Chrome and Edge.

I am out of ideas. Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: On the server, you can also specify how long images are cached. This setting is not overridden by the headers, I believe. Try to check the settings regarding caching that are available on the server.

Comment: Solved it! I had another thought about it and added date('U') into filename, so it's always unique and it worked! So the filename looks like this:
`<img src="qr/1-20220004_1668573122.png">`